# Contar registros de tres tablas SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Tabla1: "CAT_SEXO"
Campos: SEXO_ID/SEXO

Tabla2: "CONDUCTORES"
Campos: sexo_id

Tabla3: "LICENCIAS"
Campos: fecha_captura
```

por mencionar los datos de interés para mi pregunta .
El punto es que requiero consultar la ***cantidad de licencias por sexo emitidas al momento por día.***

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
SELECT COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, se.SEXO as SEXO, CAST( fecha_captura AS DATE ) as DIA 
FROM LICENCIAS lic 
join CAT_SEXO se on  se.SEXO_ID=sexo_id
join CONDUCTORES co on co.sexo_id=se.SEXO_ID
GROUP BY se.SEXO, CAST( fecha_captura AS DATE ) order by DIA desc, TOTAL asc
```

### Pero el resultado no es el que busco, puesto que me da la fecha y el sexo, pero el total no me lo da correctamente.

ANEXO: en base a los comentarios LO SIGUIENTE.

1.Tabla trámites: Campos= tramite_id, conductor_id, licencia_id. 
2.Tabla conductores: Campos= conductor_id, sexo_id. 
3.Tabla cat_sexo: Campos= SEXO_ID, SEXO. 
4.Tabla LICENCIAS: Campos= licencia_id, fecha_captura.

La tabla trámites solo serviría para relacionar con la de Licencias y conductor, de la de licencias obtendría el DIA en base a fecha_captura, de la de conductor el count es decir TOTAL sexo_id que se relaciona y compara compara con sexo_id de la tabla CAT_SEXO de esta ultima Obtendría el campo Sexo. con atención a @A.Cedano.

Quiero obtener ¿Cantidad de licencias por sexo emitidas al momento por día.? Deseo obtener algo como esto:

```css
TOTAL             SEXO                 DIA
----------------------------------------------------
15            MASCULINO          23.08.2018 00:00:00
12            FEMENINO           23.08.2018 00:00:00
```

Espero explicarme en esto último, creo se debe poder pero aún no consigo la Manera.

Comment: que resultado te da en el count?

Comment: Me arroja una cantidad super exagerada. Ejemplo entre Femenino y Masculino debe Arrojar para la fecha de hoy total=703 y solo para femenino arroja=104830657...

Comment: es por el inner join que te genera esa cantidad, ya que el join crea todas las combinaciones posibles entre las tablas, y como las vas contando, por eso te da todo eso

Comment: Bro, Tienes alguna idea de como manejarlo?, ya probé varias formas y nada.

Comment: prueba colocar en tu COUNT() el uso de DISTINCT ; de este modo COUNT(DISTINCT nombreColumna) para solo contar valores únicos @Abraham

Comment: prueba la que el maestro @Alfredo te ha dadob...

Comment: ya lo he usado!! y solo me arroja un el dato respecto al campo no los cuenta. mas bien creo que debe ser en mis condiciones después de los join!

Comment: utiliza el left join para que solo te traiga las filas relacionadas

Comment: La tabla licencia, ¿Cómo se relaciona con las otras dos? ¿Tiene conductor_id o algo? ¿Qué tipo de dato es Fecha_captura, Datetime?

Comment: Asero82, de la tabla Licencias solo tomo la fecha para asignar el día en que se emite la Licencia, en realidad no tiene relación con las otras si te refieres a un FK, y en cuanto a la de Fecha_Captura es datetime, en la tabla conductores es donde se graba el sexo_id que es tipo Booleano y está relacionado con mi tabla enumerador, para efecto de femenino y masculino....

Comment: El que la tabla `LICENCIAS` no se relacione con ninguna otra es problemático y supone un error de diseño. ¿Qué hace ahí una tabla *huérfana*? Poner en un consulta con `JOIN` una tabla así vuelve loco al sistema, porque no sabe cómo combinar los datos, con razón te arroja `104830657` registros. Debes decidir seriamente qué hacer con la tabla `LICENCIAS`. ¿A quién se le otorgan las licencias a los conductores?... entonces debes relacionarla con la tabla  `CONDUCTORES`, no la puedes dejar suelta y al querer usarla en el `JOIN`.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta para terminar de explicar el modelo de datos, en vez de hacerlo en un comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El que la tabla `LICENCIAS` no se relacione con ninguna otra es problemático y supone un error de diseño. ¿Qué hace ahí una tabla *huérfana*?

Poner en una consulta con `JOIN` una tabla así vuelve loco al sistema, porque no sabe cómo combinar los datos, con razón te arroja 104830657 registros. <s>Por lo tanto, **debes decidir seriamente qué hacer con la tabla `LICENCIAS`**. ¿A quién se le otorgan las licencias a los conductores?... entonces debes relacionarla con la tabla `CONDUCTORES`</s>, no la puedes dejar suelta y querer usarla en el JOIN de ese modo.

Ya que has explicado por completo tu modelo de datos, que hay una tabla `TRAMITES`, que era precisamente la pieza que faltaba en el puzzle, puedes escribir la consulta así:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, 
    se.SEXO as SEXO, 
    lic.fecha_captura as DIA -- no hace falta CAST si es DATETIME
FROM CONDUCTORES co 
    JOIN TRAMITES tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id
    JOIN LICENCIAS lic ON tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id
    JOIN CAT_SEXO se on  se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id
GROUP BY se.SEXO, DIA 
ORDER BY DIA DESC, TOTAL ASC;
```

Veamos el diseño completo:

### Diseño correcto

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cat_sexo 
(
    sexo_id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sexo       CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT cat_sexo_PKA01 UNIQUE (sexo)
 )ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO cat_sexo (sexo) 
    VALUES
    ('M'),
    ('F');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS conductores 
(
    conductor_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    conductor_nom  VARCHAR(50),
    sexo_id        INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (sexo_id) REFERENCES cat_sexo(sexo_id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO conductores (conductor_nom,sexo_id) 
    VALUES
    ('Pedro',1),
    ('Juana',2),
    ('María', 2),
    ('Santiago', 1),
    ('Laura',2);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS licencias 
(
    licencia_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_captura DATETIME
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO licencias (fecha_captura) 
    VALUES
    ('2018-08-21'),
    ('2018-08-22'),
    ('2018-08-20'),
    ('2018-08-21'),
    ('2018-08-22'),
    ('2018-08-23'),
    ('2018-08-18'),
    ('2018-08-19'),
    ('2018-08-20'),
    ('2018-08-21'),
    ('2018-08-19'),
    ('2018-08-22');       


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tramites 
(
    tramite_id    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    conductor_id  INT,
    licencia_id   INT,
    fecha_captura DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (conductor_id) REFERENCES conductores(conductor_id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (licencia_id) REFERENCES licencias(licencia_id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO tramites (conductor_id, licencia_id) 
    VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2),
    (2,3),
    (2,4),
    (2,5),
    (2,6),
    (3,7),
    (3,8),
    (3,9),
    (3,10),
    (4,11),
    (4,12);
```

Ahora ejecutamos la consulta modificada ligeramente. Dado que la tabla que más datos relacionados tiene es `CONDUCTORES` la ponemos de primero, así es más fácil escribir los `JOIN` y es más claro:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, 
    se.SEXO as SEXO, 
    lic.fecha_captura as DIA -- no hace falta CAST si es DATETIME
FROM CONDUCTORES co 
    JOIN TRAMITES tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id
    JOIN LICENCIAS lic ON tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id
    JOIN CAT_SEXO se on  se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id
GROUP BY se.SEXO, DIA 
ORDER BY DIA DESC, TOTAL ASC;
```

**Resultado (correcto)  con los datos hipotéticos introducidos más arriba:**

```
TOTAL       SEXO         DIA
----------------------------------------------
1            M           23.08.2018 00:00:00
1            F           22.08.2018 00:00:00
2            M           22.08.2018 00:00:00
1            F           21.08.2018 00:00:00
2            M           21.08.2018 00:00:00
2            F           20.08.2018 00:00:00
1            M           19.08.2018 00:00:00
1            F           19.08.2018 00:00:00
1            M           18.08.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### Diseño incorrecto

Para entender el motivo del error, veamos ahora el mismo diseño de más arriba, pero con una tabla `LICENCIAS2` *huérfana*. Verás cómo te devuelve los datos totalmente dislocados porque en los `JOIN` participa una tabla que el sistema no sabe cómo manejarla.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS licencias2 
    (
        licencia_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        fecha_captura DATETIME
    )ENGINE=INNODB;        

   INSERT INTO licencias2 (fecha_captura) 
        VALUES
        ('2018-08-21'),
        ('2018-08-22'),
        ('2018-08-20'),
        ('2018-08-21'),
        ('2018-08-22'),
        ('2018-08-23'),
        ('2018-08-18'),
        ('2018-08-19'),
        ('2018-08-20'),
        ('2018-08-21'),
        ('2018-08-19'),
        ('2018-08-22');
```

Escribamos la misma consulta de antes, usando esa tabla *huérfana*:

```
SELECT COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, se.SEXO as SEXO, CAST( fecha_captura AS DATE ) as DIA 
FROM LICENCIAS2 lic 
join CAT_SEXO se on  se.SEXO_ID=sexo_id
join CONDUCTORES co on co.sexo_id=se.SEXO_ID
GROUP BY se.SEXO, CAST( fecha_captura AS DATE ) order by DIA desc, TOTAL asc
```

Vamos a tener de inmediato unos resultados dislocados totalmente:

```
TOTAL       SEXO         DIA
----------------------------------------------
4           M            23.08.2018 00:00:00
6           F            23.08.2018 00:00:00
12          M            22.08.2018 00:00:00
18          F            22.08.2018 00:00:00
12          M            21.08.2018 00:00:00
18          F            21.08.2018 00:00:00
8           M            20.08.2018 00:00:00
12          F            20.08.2018 00:00:00
8           M            19.08.2018 00:00:00
12          F            19.08.2018 00:00:00
4           M            18.08.2018 00:00:00
6           F            18.08.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### Datos de prueba usados para esta respuesta

Puedes ver aquí una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](http://rextester.com/WGCF58825)**</kbd> de todo el código usado y hacer pruebas.

Comment: @Abraham ¿la respuesta resuelve o ayuda a resolver el problema? Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: de acuerdo totalmente lo que me comenta de  hecho en un inicio me supuse eso, en realidad en ese caso fue lo que ví mas factible, porque estoy realizando muestras estadísticas en cuanto a una base ya realizada y con registros. La otra opción sería preguntar, veo que tienes conocimiento más avanzado, tengo una forma quizá de relacionarlas a través de otra tabla que se llama Trámites, me gustaría saber si puedes apoyarme con los datos de la siguiente manera. Lo explico en el siguiente comentario.

Comment: 1.Tabla trámites: Campos=  tramite_id, conductor_id, licencia_id.    2.Tabla conductores: Campos=  conductor_id, sexo_id. 3.Tabla cat_sexo: Campos=  SEXO_ID, SEXO. 4.Tabla LICENCIAS: Campos=  licencia_id, fecha_captura. 
Quiero ¿Cantidad de licencias por sexo emitidas al momento por día.? La tabla trámites solo serviría para relacionar con la de Licencias y conductor, de la de licencias obtendría el día en base a fecha_captura de la de conductor el count es decir total sexo_id que se compara con sexo_id de la tabla cat_sexo de esta ultima Obtendría el campo Sexo. @A.Cedano

Comment: En efecto, la tabla `TRAMITES` era la pieza del puzzle que faltaba. La consulta puede ser más o menos así: `SELECT 
    COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, 
    se.SEXO as SEXO, 
    CAST( fecha_captura AS DATE ) as DIA 
FROM CONDUCTORES co 
    JOIN TRAMITES tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id JOIN LICENCIA lic ON tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id
    JOIN CAT_SEXO se on  se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id
GROUP BY se.SEXO, DIA 
ORDER BY DIA DESC, TOTAL ASC;` No puedo hacerte un demo ahora porque estoy desde el teléfono móvil.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Bro..  solo con unos ajustes quedó así: SELECT COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTAL, se.SEXO as SEXO, CAST( lic.fecha_captura AS DATE ) as DIA 
FROM CONDUCTORES co 
JOIN TRAMITE tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id
JOIN LICENCIAS lic ON tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id 
JOIN CAT_SEXO se on se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id
GROUP BY se.SEXO, CAST(fecha_captura AS DATE ) ORDER BY DIA DESC, TOTAL ASC, SEXO asc; y jalando al 100 :)